# AWS Redshift: How do I convert a data in varchar(7) YYYY/MM to Date type in Redshift efficiently?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, date-formatting

I have financial data that unfortunately has no day data in the date. I've already uploaded over 100GB of data into Redshift but now I want to convert the YYYY/MM varchar(y) into Date in Redshift; how should I do it efficiently?

My first thought is to create a Ruby script that connects to Redshift and transform the data from one Redshift database to another db in EC2, is there a better way of doing that in SQL or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_date` to transform strings to dates:

```
UPDATE original_table SET new_date_column = TO_DATE(varchar_date_column, 'YYYY/MM');
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html).